# How to select this entrytitle_link/_text in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON string and i need to select it. this is the data I get:

```
entry_image: "http://www.skateboard.com.au/srcImages/400300aHR0cDovL3d3dy5za2F0ZWJvYXJkLmNvbS5hdS9pbWFnZXMvc2thdGVsYW5kMS5qcGc=.jpg"
entry_image/_alt: "/skateparks/netherlands/skateland-indoor-park/"
entry_image/_source: "/srcImages/400300aHR0cDovL3d3dy5za2F0ZWJvYXJkLmNvbS5hdS9pbWFnZXMvc2thdGVsYW5kMS5qcGc=.jpg"
entryimage_link: "http://www.skateboard.com.au/skateparks/netherlands/skateland-indoor-park/"
entryimage_link/_source: "/skateparks/netherlands/skateland-indoor-park/"
entrytitle_link: "http://www.skateboard.com.au/skateparks/netherlands/skateland-indoor-park/"
entrytitle_link/_source: "/skateparks/netherlands/skateland-indoor-park/"
entrytitle_link/_text: "Skateland Indoor Park"
```

now i can select the img successfully with:

```
parks.results[i].entry_image
```

but i cant seem to select the `parks.results[i].entry_image` with:

```
parks.results[i].entrytitle_link/_text
```

I think it's the '/' doing this, what can i do to select it?

Comment: Use bracket notation: `parks.results[i]['entrytitle_link/_text']`

Comment: Wow thanks!! thats it!

Comment: This dit it! Add the awenser, so i can approve it.

Answer (score 1):

Enclose properties having `-` or `/` (in your case) with a quote like:

```
parks.results[i]['entrytitle_link/_text']
```

The `/` is not a good practice with JSON objects, using `_` is recommended.